# Como pegar a quantidade de várias propriedades em uma lista?

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma lista que possui mais de 10 mil Grades Curriculares.
Dentro de Grade Curriculares possuo o nome da Disciplina e o Ensino que ele se encontra

Existem 15 matérias que podem se repetir para cada Ensino.

**Ex:**

> Ensino Fundamental possui as disciplinas de matemática, português e
> ciências.
>
> Ensino Médio possui inglês, física e biologia, matemática e
> português.

Preciso pegar a quantidade de cada disciplina que exista em cada ensino e o somatório da mesma disciplina em todos os ensinos.

Alguém tem alguma maneira simples de conseguir pegar essas informações?
Pensei em fazer um `foreach` para cada disciplina, mas ficaria gigantesco o código.

**Eu tenho um `Dto` que possui:**

```
public int AnoConcurso { get; set; } 
public List<RelatorioDisciplinasDto> ComponenetesCurriculares { get; set; }
```

**Dentro de `RelatorioDisciplinasDto`:**

```
public int CodigoNivelEnsino { get; set; } 
public string NivelEnsino { get; set; } 
public string Disciplina { get; set; }
```

O problema é que no `groupBy` quando digito `grade.ComponenetesCurriculares` e depois coloco .(ponto), ele não enxerga `Disciplina`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo enunciado que deu montei um exemplo para conseguir mostrar a resposta e ficar mais claro.

**Classe existente:**

```
public class RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
  public int CodigoNivelEnsino { get; set; } 
  public string NivelEnsino { get; set; } 
  public string Disciplina { get; set; }
}
```

**Exemplo na consola:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    List<RelatorioDisciplinasDto> grades = new List<RelatorioDisciplinasDto>();

    //Ensino Médio possui inglês, física e biologia, matemática e português.
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 1, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Médio", Disciplina = "Inglês"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 1, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Médio", Disciplina = "Física"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 1, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Médio", Disciplina = "Biologia"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 1, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Médio", Disciplina = "Matemática"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 1, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Médio", Disciplina = "Português"
    });

    //Ensino Fundamental possui as disciplinas de matemática, português e ciências.
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 2, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Fundamental", Disciplina = "Matemática"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 2, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Fundamental", Disciplina = "Português"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 2, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Fundamental", Disciplina = "Ciências"
    });
    grades.Add(new RelatorioDisciplinasDto{
      CodigoNivelEnsino = 2, NivelEnsino = "Ensino Fundamental", Disciplina = "Ciências"
    });

    var quantidadeDeCadaDisciplinasPorEnsino = grades
      .GroupBy(
        grade => grade.NivelEnsino,
        grade => grade.Disciplina,
        (nivelEnsino, disciplinas) => new 
        {
          TipoDeEnsino = nivelEnsino,
          CountDisciplinas = disciplinas.Count(),
          Disciplinas = disciplinas
        }
      );

    Console.WriteLine("\nQuantidade de cada disciplina que exista em cada ensino:\n");

    foreach (var result in quantidadeDeCadaDisciplinasPorEnsino)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Tipo de Ensino: " + result.TipoDeEnsino);
        Console.WriteLine("Número de Disciplinas: " + result.CountDisciplinas);
        var group = result.Disciplinas
          .GroupBy(s => s)
          .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
        foreach (var disciplina in group){
            Console.WriteLine("Nome da Disciplina: " + disciplina.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Quantidade: " + disciplina.Count);
          }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n----------------------------\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Somatório das disciplinas em todos os ensinos:\n");

    var somatorioDeCadaDisciplina = grades
      .Select(grade => grade.Disciplina)
      .GroupBy(s => s)
      .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });

    foreach (var result in somatorioDeCadaDisciplina)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Nome da Disciplina: " + result.Name);
      Console.WriteLine("Quantidade: " + result.Count);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Eu tenho um Dto que possui:

        public int AnoConcurso { get; set; }        
        public List<RelatorioDisciplinasDto> ComponenetesCurriculares { get; set; 

Dentro de RelatorioDisciplinasDto:

public int CodigoNivelEnsino { get; set; }
        public string NivelEnsino { get; set; }
        public string Disciplina { get; set; }

O problema é que no groupBy quando digito grade.ComponenetesCurriculares e depois coloco .(ponto), ele não enxerga Disciplina.
 .GroupBy(
             grade => grade.ComponenetesCurriculares,

Comment: Meu RelatorioEstatisticaDtojá está chegando no serviço com as informações que quero.
public int AnoConcurso { get; set; }        
        public List<RelatorioDisciplinasDto> ComponenetesCurriculares { get; set; }
Dái essa lista vem o nome da disciplina o NivelEnsino. Porém quando coloco no GroupBy, não consigo acessar disciplina chamando por grade.ComponenetesCurriculares.
Na teoria seria grade.ComponenetesCurriculares.Disciplina.

Comment: Foi, mil desculpas. =(

Comment: Muito obrigado. Sei nem como agradecer.

Comment: Agradeço mesmo. Desculpa por não ter colocado as informações completas.

Comment: @ThunAnFreitasChiu se ajudei a obter a resposta coloque a resposta como [aceite](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta)